# Google trends specific location

Tags: google-search, google-trends

I am a new user of Google Trends, I want to do research on location trends, at the moment the segmentation I am doing is only by city, can a more specific search like neighborhood, street or quarter be done?

Answer (score 0):

City is the smallest granularity provided by Google Trends.
However in the US counties might also be useful since in some places they can be finer grained than cities.